# How we can show that $\:I_n\ge \frac{2}{\pi }\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, summation

We have $I_n=\int _{\pi }^{2\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(nx\right)\right|}{x}\:dx,$ and we need to show that$\:I_n\ge \frac{2}{\pi }\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$
I write $I_n=\int _{\pi }^{2\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(nx\right)\right|}{x}\:dx=\int _{n\pi }^{2n\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(t\right)\right|}{t}dt$ . My teacher advised me to write $\int _{n\pi }^{2n\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(t\right)\right|}{t}dt$ like a sum of integrals to continue, but I don't understand why and how... I want to understand not just to solve!

P.S.: I write $\int _{n\pi }^{2n\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(t\right)\right|}{t}dt=\sum _{k=n}^{^{2n-1}}\:\int _{k\pi }^{\left(k+1\right)\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(t\right)\right|}{t}dt$ , and now how we can continue to show that inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Just find a lower bound for $\frac{|\sin(t)|}{t}$. Since the bounds don't change too much, a first attempt would be $\int_{kπ}^{(k+1)π} \frac{|\sin(t)|}{t}\ dt \ge \int_{kπ}^{(k+1)π} \frac{|\sin(t)|}{(k+1)π}\ dt$. You should be able to continue from here.

Comment: hmmm, yes from here I know to continue, but my question is the following: How you realize that $\int_{kπ}^{(k+1)π} \frac{|\sin(t)|}{t}\ dt \ge \int_{kπ}^{(k+1)π} \frac{|\sin(t)|}{(k+1)π}\ dt$ ? and nothing else...

Comment: @Lucas: The inequality is correct because $t \le (k+1)π$, but if you're asking why we pick that, it is more-or-less arbitrary. Usually the goal of finding such inequalities is to obtain bounds on integrals that have no closed form. So one obvious way would be to just use a constant to bound the denominator. This merely gives one bound on the integral, which happens to be the one you are asked to prove. To get better bounds, we would have to find a better bound for the integrand.

Comment: What do you mean? $\int f \le \int g$ on the same interval if $f \le g$ on that interval. It has nothing to do with whether it is denominator or not.

Comment: if we have $\int _{k\pi }^{\left(2k+3\right)\pi }\:\frac{|\sin \left(t\right)|}{t}\:dt\:$ it is $\ge $ then $\int _{k\pi }^{\left(2k+3\right)\pi }\:\frac{|\sin \left(t\right)|}{\left(2k+3\right)\pi }\:dt$ I've right? I mean the constant to bound from denominator is always $\int _a^b\:$  b? where b is Integration ends

Comment: @Lucas: No. If you don't understand, you should not ask for a method to get the answer. It would be invariably wrong. For example $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{5-x^2}\ dx \ge \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{5-1^2}\ dx$ is false, and $\int_{-2}^1 \frac{1}{5-x^2}\ dx \ge \int_{-2}^1 \frac{1}{5-(-2)^2}\ dx$ is false also. And $\int_1^2 \frac{x-x^2}{x}\ dx \ge \int_1^2 \frac{x-x^2}{2}\ dx$ is false as well.

Comment: @Lucas: We are using the fact that given any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and functions $f,g$ that are integrable on $[a,b]$, and $f(x) \le g(x)$ for any $x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx \le \int_a^b g(x)\ dx$. If you cannot see how this applies here, you should ask a separate question, because it is a problem with basic foundations.